# How to get a list of databases that include a table with value in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to get a list of databases that include a table (social_activists_ AND have a value inside it of (activist_id =1).
activist_id is a column.

I tried:

```
select table_schema as database_name from information_schema.tables where table_type = 'BASE TABLE' and table_name = 'social_activists' and activist_id =1;
```

But it did not work. any idea?

Comment: Build a sql query from information_schema.tables  ,execute as prepared statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a series of SQL queries this way:

```
SELECT CONCAT(
  'SELECT ', QUOTE(t.table_schema), ' AS table_schema, * ', 
  'FROM `', t.table_schema, '`.`', t.table_name, '` ',
  'WHERE activist_id = 1;'
 ) AS _query
FROM information_schema.tables t
JOIN information_schema.columns c USING (table_schema, table_name) 
WHERE t.table_type = 'BASE TABLE' 
 AND t.table_name = 'social_activists' 
 AND c.column_name = 'activist_id';
```

Then you have to write some application code to prepare and execute the queries one at a time.

I included the table_schema as the first column of the generated query so you have some indication of which table contains the value you're looking for.

I included the join to information_schema.columns just in case there exists a table named `social_activists` with no column `activist_id`.